# php glob absolute path issue

Tags: php, glob

I have two WinServer 2008 machines running the same code. One server only has a single drive ("c:/") and the this code runs and returns folder names.

```
// Code works on server with a single C: drive - returns folder names
$path_x = "c:/path_to_files/";
foreach(glob($path_x . '*', GLOB_NOSORT) as $fullpath_folder){
```

However, when I run this code on the server with c:, d:, and e: drives, I get nothing. The code is running on C: under inetpub/wwwroot but is searching the e: drive, which may be the reason it works on the single drive server.

```
// Returns nothing on server with C:, D:, & E: drives (code running in inetpub on c:)
$path_x = "e:/path_to_files/";
foreach(glob($path_x . '*', GLOB_NOSORT) as $fullpath_folder){
```

Any recommendations are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Most likely permissions.  `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');` will tell you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have IUSR and IIS_IUSRS set with the same permissions that work on the other server (read & exe, modify, etc.)

Comment: Setting page-specific error reporting did not reveal any errors.